# Python raw_input following sys.stdin.read() throws EOFError

Tags: python

a similar question has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833526/python-user-input-eof-error-question-with-sys-stdin-readlines), but the answers suggested a workaround which is not applicable to my situation.

An email message is piped from mutt to a script, and is read from STDIN:

```
message = sys.stdin.read()
# message is parsed and URLs are printed as a list to choose from...
selected_index = raw_input('Which URL to open?')
```

I understand that raw_input() will get the EOF left by read(), but is there a way to 'reset' STDIN?

Comment: What system are you on? On Linux, this works fine!

Comment: Mac OS X (10.7). Alex Martelli suggested re-opening STDIN [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197891/how-to-handle-eoferror-for-raw-input-in-python-in-mac-os-x), but that does not seem to work for me.

Comment: I just confirmed that the very same exception is thrown on a GNU/Linux system (CentOS). When I manually feed STDIN (terminating the input with CTRL-D), the script works fine, but calling `./script.py < message` produces the problem described above.

Comment: OS X had similar problems in the past, but they were supposed to be [fixed](http://bugs.python.org/issue1706039) in Python 2.7 (I'm on 2.7.1).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
message = sys.stdin.read()
sys.stdin = open('/dev/tty')
selected_index = raw_input('Which URL to open?')
```

This works on Linux; maybe it will work for OSX too.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work (this is the solution proposed for the question I linked to in my first post). In the modified form, the script awaits input **before** arriving at the raw_input function, and the error occurs once I hit return.

Comment: This is odd – I must have done something wrong before: It works now. Thanks!

Comment: Nice hack!  Linux FTW

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset STDIN using `sys.stdin.seek(0)`

Reference: http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html

Comment: That helps a bit – the EOFError exception is gone, but the raw_input is now ignored entirely (i.e. the script proceeds without waiting for user input).