# EOFError when using input() after using sys.stdin.buffer.read()

Tags: linux, python-3.x

I'm currently writing a python program on linux which will accept a binary stream via `sys.stdin.buffer.read()`, and then I'd like it to accept input interactively afterward using `input()`.

Here is a completely contrived example which illustrates my issue:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys 

buf = b"Garbage Data"
#comment out the following line to avoid the EOFError:
buf = sys.stdin.buffer.read()

with open("outTempFile", 'wb') as f:
    f.write(buf)

print("Please enter your name:")
buf2 = input("First:\t")
print("Your first name is:\t{}".format(buf2))
```

When I run this program with a stdin input, I get the following error/output:

`-> % cat contrivedExample.py | ./contrivedExample.py
    Please enter your name:
    First:  Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "./contrivedExample.py", line 11, in <module>
        buf2 = input("First:\t")
    EOFError: EOF when reading a line`

The output file, `outTempFile` does get written to, however the call to `input()` fails with the `EOFError`. I'm guessing this is because `STDIN` is tied to the pipe I used in the command-line invocation of the script.

When I comment out line #6 and run the program with the same invocation:

`-> % cat contrivedExample.py | ./contrivedExample.py`

I get the following output:

`Please enter your name:
First:  Your first name is: #!/usr/bin/env python3`

Which tells me that `input()` is indeed reading `STDIN` from the pipe (`|`) provided on the command line.

My question is how I can switch the program from reading in via the pipe (`|`) to reading in via interactive terminal prompt (as is usually done via `input()`)?

Comment: I finally found the answer in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034595/python-raw-input-following-sys-stdin-read-throws-eoferror

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found is after reading from STDIN via a linux pipe (`|`) to simply replace `sys.stdin` with `open('/dev/tty')` which allows `input()` to read from my terminal:

```
echo "hello" | python -c 'import sys; buf = sys.stdin.read(); print(buf); sys.stdin=open("/dev/tty"); buf2=input(); print(buf2)'
```