# Getting EOF error and not able to figure out the reason

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the below code I am getting a EOF error. I am not able to figure out the reason.If I use input() instead of sys.stdin.read() code works fine.I think my problem is similar to one in the link [Python raw_input following sys.stdin.read() throws EOFError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034595/python-raw-input-following-sys-stdin-read-throws-eoferror)

When I do print(input_str) it doesnot print anything, console just skips a line. It is not asking for any inputs.
Printing input_list, error given below is generated.
NameError: name 'input_list' is not defined.

```
import ast,sys
input_str = sys.stdin.read()
input_list = ast.literal_eval(input_str)
C = input_list[0]
F = input_list[1]
H = input_list[2]
k=set(C).intersection(set(F)).intersection(set(H))
```

Code error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\z003p4nk\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3267, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-14-dd3473bf412a>", line 5, in <module>
    input_list = ast.literal_eval(input_str)

  File "C:\Users\z003p4nk\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\ast.py", line 46, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')

  File "C:\Users\z003p4nk\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\ast.py", line 35, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)

  File "<unknown>", line unknown

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Comment: That's the expected result for `ast.literal_eval("")`. You need to make sure `input_str` is *not* empty. You should probably use `input()` instead of `sys.stdin.read()`, since the form takes a line of input, while the latter reads until you *close* standard input.

Answer (score 0):

`sys.stdin.read()` will only read in a line that is terminated with Ctrl-D, while `input()` will read in a line once it receives the enter key. As Chepner said, you must close the standard input by using Ctrl-D in order for the function to read in the line.